# taxonomy view only works with un-aliased paths

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I've created a custom view to display my taxonomies. With URL alias (pathauto) setup on the taxonomy/term/% path I would expect that the aliased url would display my view. Instead I get a blank page.

If I browse to the un-aliased path ie /taxonomy/term/15/ it all works. Any ideas why this happens? I've seen the Path redirect module, Sub-pathauto module, and Global Redirect module, but i'm pretty sure this should just work without any other modules. Apart from that I don't want to take my changes with yet another module, so close before my deadline ;)

Comment: How does your aliased url looks like? Are you using any arguments or contextual filter in views? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18291/views-wont-handle-my-pathauto-pattern-for-taxonomy-pages?rq=1

Comment: I've used this method: http://www.webbykat.com/2012/04/overriding-default-taxonomy-page-view-drupal-7 to override the default taxonomy page with a view in Drupal 7. Now this works perfectly, except that this view only gets "triggered" with the un-aliased url path. With the aliased url path, drupal just shows me the default taxonomy page.

I use it with and without additional arguments/contextual filters.

I currently have changed the default path: taxonomy/term/% to tags/% but even when I changed that back to the default i still the same, works for un-aliased url, and not for aliased url.